# How to log user in Elmah which is implemented in Web Api

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, elmah

I have implemented elmah in web api application using **Elmah.contrib.webapi**.My mobile application is using that Api and It works fine.My problem is, I am getting user field empty.How can I log user name or id to **Elmah Error_Table**.

Answer (score 0):

ELMAH fills the *User* field with the value of `Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.Name`. Most identity frameworks sets the current principal when the user logs in.

Which kind of authentication are you using?

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to recompile Elmah, we can use a global method, which populates Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.Name before calling elmah.

```
        public static void LogError(Exception exception, string username)
        {
            Thread.CurrentPrincipal = new GenericPrincipal(new GenericIdentity(username), new string[] {});
            Elmah.ErrorSignal.FromCurrentContext().Raise(exception);
        }
```